# How to stop playback in PiP iOS

Tags: ios, swift, picture-in-picture

I am building a video player library that supports only a limited number of formats. I expect host app will choose other player for unsupported formats.

My player will have also have Picture-in-Picture support. Scenario is that suppose a video is playing in my player in PiP mode and user clicks on another video that is incompatible with my player. How would my player would know that?

I have tried using Audio Interruption Notification but I guess that doesn't work for interruptions in same app.

Comment: "suppose a video is playing in my player in PiP mode and user clicks on another video" Don't let the user do that. Your app should be unusable unless the user stops PiP mode.

Comment: Yes, that is a way to do it. But I'm working on a library here and your solution would work with host app.